# Is ($\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$,*) a free abelian group with countable basis?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I can not find a way to prove that the abelian group ($\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$,*) is a free abelian group with countable basis. Is is even true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the positive rationals are the free abelian group whose basis consists of the primes:
$$
(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\cdot) \cong \bigoplus_{p\in \mathbb{P}} \mathbb Z.
$$ 
This follows more or less directly from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.
Clearly the primes $\mathbb{P}$ are countable (and the whole group is countable anyway).

Answer (score 3):

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, any natural number can be expressed as $p_1^{k_1}\cdot \dots \cdot p_n^{k_n}$, where $p_i$ are primes and $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Extending this to positive rationals, any positive rational can be expressed in the form $p_1^{k_1}\cdot \dots \cdot p_n^{k_n}$, where $p_i$ are primes and $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. This makes it into a free abelian group with $p_i$ as a basis.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a free abelian group which is generated by prime numbers (basis elements).